# When does the LLN fails?

Tags: probability

When does the variance of each element of the sequence increases so fast as to invalidate the convergence of the mean?

Comment: The point of the LLN is that the elements are IID (independent and identically distributed). Are you looking for a weaker hypothesis than IID where the LLN still holds? Or, rather, how far away from IID you need to take it before LLN fails?

Comment: Absolutely, for example when the elements in the sequence are independent but their variance may go to infinity

Comment: Though if i.i.d. random variables had finite expectation and infinite variance then the Law of Large Numbers still applies, even though the sample average  would also have finite expectation and infinite variance